# How do I write a start script for my ark server?

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts

I am currently trying to install a ARK dedicated server on my Ubuntu server 22.04.1 I followed the entire tutorial from [Dedicated_server_setup](https://ark.fandom.com/wiki/Dedicated_server_setup) everything worked so far, until I tried to write the start script.

I opened nano copied the script given on the site,

```
#! /bin/bash
./ShooterGameServer TheIsland?listen?SessionName=<server_name>?ServerPassword=<join_password>?ServerAdminPassword=<admin_password> -server -log
```

edited the admin password, join password, and the server name. now having this:

```
#! /bin/bash
./ShooterGameServer TheIsland?listen?SessionName=Unlegitsserver?ServerPassword=Testpassword?ServerAdminPassword=testpassword1 -server -log
```

which I saved as `start.sh` if i execute the script with `./start.sh` it doesn't do anything but giving me this:

```
./start.sh: line 2: ./ShooterGameServer: No such file or directory
```

I googled now for an hour, and haven't found anything similar to my issue. I also tried different scripts but all of em give me exactly the same error. I am pretty new to this, and don't know what to do now.

On Windows I used the same script, only with different path of course. and there it worked without any issues at all.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Thankies! -Unlegit

Comment: Are you editing the script on Windows or some other OS than Ubuntu?

Comment: No, i edit the script in the command line to which i connected per ssh. using nano.

Comment: where else am i supposed to ask that? i've never experienced any issues with the exact same script before on windows servers or anything. so i thought it's something ubuntu specific.

Comment: Are you executing the script *within* the same directory as the game server executable called "ShooterGameServer'?

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute paths in scripts:

```
#! /bin/bash
/full/path/to/ShooterGameServer TheIsland?listen?SessionName=Unlegitsserver?ServerPassword=Testpassword?ServerAdminPassword=testpassword1 -server -log
```